# hazelcast instance and group name : best practices

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have configured hazelcast for dev and QA environment and kept hazelcast instance name same but different group name ( in each yml files ). Is this correct ?  Also, is there any way to limit the cluster members. It will just join the explicitly configured members with port no.  Could you guide to some sample examples.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Hazelcast ? YML config so it's 3.12 or 4.*.  4.0 has `hazelcast.member.naming.moby.enabled` which might solve your naming problem. Other questions perhaps belong on separate posts.

Comment: Samples - https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples

Answer (score 5):

### Avoid joining to extraneous clusters

Defining different group names (3.y versions) or cluster name (4.y versions) is the correct way.

If you want to stick to the default multicast join mechanism (see next section), you should also change the multicast group (IP address) or port for each of the Hazelcast clusters (dev, QA, prod).

**Sample 3.12.6:**

```java
Config config = new Config();
config.getGroupConfig().setName("devCluster");
config.getNetworkConfig()
  .getJoin()
  .getMulticastConfig()
  .setMulticastGroup("224.0.190.1");
Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

YAML:

- https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/v3.12.6/hazelcast/src/test/resources/hazelcast-fullconfig-without-network.yaml#L36-L37
- https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/v3.12.6/hazelcast/src/test/resources/hazelcast-fullconfig.yaml#L53-L54

**Sample 4.0:**

```java
Config config = new Config().setClusterName("devCluster");
config.getNetworkConfig()
  .getJoin()
  .getMulticastConfig()
  .setMulticastGroup("224.0.190.1");
Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

YAML:

- https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/v4.0/hazelcast/src/test/resources/hazelcast-fullconfig-without-network.yaml#L36

### Defining members by host and port - use TCP/IP joiner

Hazelcast IMDG uses multicast cluster discovery method by default. If you want to specify members by their IP addresses and ports, then disable the multicast and use the TCP/IP discovery instead.

**Sample:**

```java
JoinConfig joinConfig = config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin();
joinConfig.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
joinConfig.getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true)
  // either without port (then port range 5701-5703 is tried)
  .addMember("172.17.0.2")
  // or with the port specified
  .addMember("172.17.0.3:25001")
  .addMember("172.17.0.3:25002");
```

YAML:

- https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/v4.0/hazelcast/src/test/resources/hazelcast-fullconfig.yaml#L50-L69